# Is there any way this property of semigroups can be satisfied?

Tags: heat-equation, semigroups-of-operators, integral-kernel

Suppose you have the heat semigroup $(S(t))_{t>0}$, such that

$$S(t)u(x) = (4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|x-y|^2/4t}u(y)dy.$$

The semigroup has the property that

$$S(t)S(s)u(x) = S(t+s)u(x).$$

I'm interested to know if there is, or if it's possible to show what happens with

$$ S(t)\left(v(x)S(s)u(x) \right) $$
for example, if there is any relationship of this term with
$$ S(t)\left(S(s)u(x)v(x) \right).$$

Developing the integrals of these terms, we have that of the first is
$$(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|x-y|^2/4t}v(y) (4\pi s)^{-n/2}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|y-z|^2/4s}u(z)dz\right)dz dy.$$
and the second is
$$(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|x-y|^2/4t} (4\pi s)^{-n/2}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|y-z|^2/4}u(z)v(z)dz\right)dz dy.$$
is it possible to establish relations of the type $\leq$ or $\geq$ between these integrals? Even if it is necessary to impose restrictions on $u$ or $v$. for example, if $u(x)=|x|$, it is possible to find that
$$
\begin{split}
(4\pi t)^{-n/2} &\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|x-y|^2/4t}|y| (4\pi s)^{-n/2}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|y-z|^2/4s}v(z)dz\right)dz dy \\&\leq (4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|x-y|^2/4t} (4\pi s)^{-n/2}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|y-z|^2/4}|z|v(z)dz\right)dz dy
\end{split}$$

or $\geq$. I haven't found anything so far talking about it, so I'd be happy for any info on that.

Comment: (1) I don't see how there could possibly be any general inequalities relating the two. Your expression is bilinear in $(u,v)$. If there are any inequalities, replacing $v\mapsto -v$ will give you the opposite sign, contradicting the purported inequalities.

Comment: (2) Consider the case $u$ and $v$ are both non-negative functions but with disjoint support. Then $S_tS_s(uv) \equiv 0$ but $S_t(v S_s u)$ is positive everywhere for $t > 0$. // Because of these two points, I feel this question is too much of a fishing expedition. Can you at least provide either a motivation for asking this problem or some further discussion so that we have a better sense of what kinds of answers you are looking for?